# Can I use any GPRS Arduino shield with a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: arduino, gsm

I would like to send data over the Mobile network using a Raspberry Pi.
Can I buy any GPRS shield made for Arduino like this one http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/GPRS_Shield_V2.0 and connect it wire by wire to a raspberry pi?
Will I then need a library like arduPi du communicate with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i see in the description of the shield that PWM is required, the raspberry does not support PWM. so i do not think that this will work... 
why you are not using a simple usb gsm stick? i think this is the most easy way...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [This one](http://www.elecfreaks.com/store/gprsgsm-shield-efcom-p-415.html) from ElecFreaks:

[image]

using [this adapter](http://www.elecfreaks.com/store/rpi-gsm-adapter-p-713.html)

[image]

The shield is programmed via a serial port, using AT commands.

There is information in the Elecfreaks site regarding the AT programming for making calls and sending/receiving SMS, including a sample sketches for arduino, but nothing related to gprs operation.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.amazon.in/Huawei-E303F-E303FH-Data-White/dp/B00HQABD4Y/ref=sr_1_7?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1455037801&sr=1-7&keywords=usb+3g+dongle

This one will work according to this link: http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#USB_3G_Dongles

Comment: Adding a country specific link for a transient offer on an admittedly well known on-line retailer is not really what we are looking for here.  If you have personal experience or other information strongly supporting this particular item then I guess that would be useful, however your first link will probably rot after a while - limiting its usefulness.  The second link is helpful in that it lists a number of devices that are known to work - but as this is an old question that reference was not available to the OP at the time they asked otherwise they may well have found it themselves IMHO!